# IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started on new Thread

Tags: android, java-threads

I'm using HockeyApp to catch crash issues from internal testers and a single crash report with this trace came in:

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
at java.lang.Thread.checkNotStarted(Thread.java:849)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1059)
at com.myapp.service.ApiService.connect(ApiService.java:258)
at com.myapp.service.ApiService.connect(ApiService.java:250)
at com.myapp.service.ApiService.connectForRecord(ApiService.java:748)
at com.fmyapp.service.ApiService.connectForRecord(ApiService.java:733)
at com.myapp.service.ApiService.getOxiChekList(ApiService.java:703)
at com.myapp.service.ApiService.access$1200(ApiService.java:35)
at com.myapp.service.ApiService$1.run(ApiService.java:420)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

After looking over SO it looks like the issue is that the code is calling onStart() after the thread has finished. However the only code in my service which calls onStart() is below. Note that it is started after a NEW thread has been created. This has only happened once so I'm not certain on any repro steps but I'm curious if anyone else knows what could cause this.

Line 256-260 (crash at line 258)

```
private void connect(ApiMethod apiMethod, Token authToken, long apiRefKey, String[] urlParams, Object... params) {
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(apiMethod, authToken, apiRefKey, urlParams, params);
    mConnectThread.start();
    mIsRunning = true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe show some more code? `ConnectThread` and `ApiService` could be helpful.

Comment: I added the entire method, hesitant to include the entire file as its ~800 lines. The code was only added as background info showing that I am calling `start()` directly after the `new` so there is no chance the thread is already started.

Comment: Can you show what happens around here "ApiService.java:420". Also one of your package names is "fmyapp" instead of "myapp", I assume that is a typo?

Comment: Typo, I had to change to change it as I left company info in the app name.

Comment: Ok, I thought of one way this could happen. If `connect()` is called from within another `Thread` as it seems it is, and `mConnectThread` is a member of some outer class, then if two threads call `connect()` at the same time, both could call `start()` on the same instance of `mConnectThread`. If this is possible depends on the rest of your code, which we can't see. You could synchronize access to `connect()` to prevent this, but you probably have other issues if two threads are running this simultaneously.

Comment: Are you sure the thread isn't started in the constructor of `ConnectThread`? Does the thread start if you remove the invocation to `mConnectThread.start()`

Comment: @Daniel it definitely doesn't, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @ci_ It shouldn't be called by another thread though your suggestion does give it reason to be a 1 in a 100 scenario. I'll continue with that in mind and see if I can solve it; I understand that without giving any more code there isn't much to be done, I'll see what I can do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your case intrigues me. How about overriding `start()` in `ConnectThread`, invoking `super.start()` in the overridden method and log the invocation with `Thread.currentThread().getName();` and/or maybe throwing in a `new Exception().printStackTrace(System.err);` It should shed some light on the issue.

Comment: @RobVoisey I still think you should post some more code. You say it shouldn't be called from another thread, however we can clearly see com.myapp.service.ApiService$1.run(ApiService.java:420) in your stack trace which tells us the opposite.

Comment: @ci_ Apologies, I meant that `connect()` should not be called from within the `ConnectThread`. There was a tangle of threads which meant that the service was handling an intent via `onHandleIntent` which then started a new thread to determine how it should be handled, which then lead to `connect()`. I've added a bit of debugging code so that I can see whats happening around the time a tester exerpiences the crash though we're probably going to just refactor it heavily to remove the amount of threads generated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue,
i checked for whether the State of thread is `terminated` and re initiated the thread and my problem is solved, hope this will help you

For ex:

```
if(mythread.getState().equals(Thread.State.TERMINATED)) {
    mythread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(status == GameStatus.Running) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        timelapsed += 1;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```